# How do you reset your spawnpoint back to your bed after doing a stupid thing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I did a stupid thing and accidentally set my spawn place to where I was lost.  I don't want to lose all my stuff but I went travelling with my boat and now I'm just really confused.  The java help pages and all that are completely impenetrable to me, how do I find my bed and then go back to get my stuff and then go back to my bed again.  (Please explain as if I'm a complete novice to computers.)

Also, where do you put coordinates in to go there and how.

Answer (score 5):

The command to set your spawn to any x, y, and x coordinate is:

```
/spawnpoint <player> <x> <y> <z>
```

and the first spawn point is within 255 blocks of X; 0, Z: 0.

Comment: You could also just do __/spawnpoint__ and it will set your spawnpoint to your current location.

Comment: @DatEpicCoderGuyWhoPrograms The OP has stated that his current spawn location is not where he wants to be, so `/spawnpoint` would not be helpful in this situation.

Comment: @Ben I know, I thought it could be helpful for him in the future if he does get lost again, he would have set his spawn to his desired location.

Answer (score 3):

The ONLY way to reset your spawn point is to sleep in a bed. If this spawn point is obstructed, it will spawn you into the wilderness, just like when you first made the world.

For your second question, the only way without a mod (I think) is to look at your map (or use console commands) and write down the coordinates. Then use console commands to find the coordinates.

Hope this helped!

Edit: type /help for console commands

Comment: You can find your co-ordinates using F3, and as @cantido said - You use `/spawnpoint [username] [x] [y] [z]` in the chat.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't wonder to far after you first entered the world you play in, your can always press F3 and they to walk to X=0, Y=anything Z=0 (top left of the screen).

Answer (score -1):

**It would be a bit easier to...**

Use `/spawnpoint <username> <x> <y> <z>` for the respawning thing and you can do `/gamerule keepinventory = true` to keep your stuff. To find the coordinates, you can just hit F3 and it will tell you your coordinates and a bunch of other cool stuff.

If you want to do it where you're going back and forth or you have your world set to no cheats, you can get a mod called REI's Minimap that says where you last died and other stuff. But in this situation you really can't set your spawnpoint (unless you sleep in a bed) or keep your stuff.

Answer (score -4):

You can just type `/spawnpoint` in the chat/commands then it will say 'Set (your name)s spawn point to so and so.